# Vue3 JS - How to access/print values stored in an object onto document <template>

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

New to Vue, JS and Firebase been taking tutorials for weeks and now trying to build a test project.  Embarrassed to say I have been stuck on this particular problem for several days.  Trying to write this question as best I can given my current level of understanding which is pretty basic.

**Desired Outcome:** What I am trying to do is query firebase database to get the last event created by current user so that, if it exists, I can then pre-fill some of the Vue form data when they create their next entry.

Sounds simple enough but my tutorials only cover single document retrieval/display when you already have the document id, OR, how to retrieve and display all documents from a collection in a list.  My need is hybrid in that don't know the document ID until I query to get it and every attempt to combine the functionality from tutorials has failed...multiple times.

Currently, I am able to query the DB just fine and can verify it returns the results I want to an object which I can log to the console and 'see', but, can't for the life of me figure out how to get to the data within that object once back on the doc template.

**JS Code (getLastEvent-SO.js)**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { db } from '@/firebase/config'
import { collection, getDocs, query, where, orderBy, limit } from 'firebase/firestore'

const getLastEvent = (u) => { // u = user id
    const lastEvent = ref([])
    let collectionRef = collection(db, 'events') // establish reference
    collectionRef = query(collectionRef, where("userId", "==", u ), orderBy("created", "desc"), limit(1))  // should return last event if exists   
    getDocs(collectionRef)
        .then(snapshot => {
            let docs = []
            let eId = null
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {  // using a loop because I couldnt figure out how to get a single doc without first having the id of that doc which I don't know until I query to get users last event created
                docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
            })
            lastEvent.value = docs // assign value of docs to lastEvent
        })
  console.log('lastEvent1:', lastEvent) // console display proves the record stored is the one I want but how do I access/print to console the values?

  return { lastEvent }
}
export default getLastEvent
```

**Vue Code:**

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <h2>New event</h2>
    <p v-if="lastEvent">Last Start Date: {{ lastEvent.startDate }} </p>  <!-- PROBLEM: this will NOT display - why??? --> 
    ...more form inputs...
    <button>Add event</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import getUser from "@/composables/getUser";
import getLastEvent from "@/composables/getLastEvent-SO";
export default {
  setup() {
    // Query last user event created so default form values based on last entry can be set
    const { user } = getUser();
    const { lastEvent } = getLastEvent(user.value.uid)
    return { lastEvent };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Copied from Chrome/console (lastEvent):**

```
{
    "__v_isShallow": false,
    "dep": {
        "w": 0,
        "n": 0
    },
    "__v_isRef": true,
    "_rawValue": [
        {
            "userId": "H0jZIKGTggeX4DsjucGR50Cb8663",
            "reservation": "",
            "startDate": "2022-07-07",
            "created": 1656595528420,
            "location": "mpmCHrVYDK9icr3yTnYG",
            "startTime": "09:00a",
            "type": "Open",
            "duration": 1,
            "id": "ZHnbrLWkYO9gHdjKiygk"
        }
    ],
    "_value": [
        {
            "userId": "H0jZIKGTggeX4DsjucGR50Cb8663",
            "reservation": "",
            "startDate": "2022-07-07",
            "created": 1656595528420,
            "location": "mpmCHrVYDK9icr3yTnYG",
            "startTime": "09:00a",
            "type": "Open",
            "duration": 1,
            "id": "ZHnbrLWkYO9gHdjKiygk"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any hint as to why I am unable to access the data from within the document template as {{ lastEvent.startDate }} ??

[edit: added this screen-shot of the console where I copied the object from by request]

[Screen shot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDjKl.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure, but the method getDocs returns a Promise. So, try to await getDocs before to return { lastEvent }.

Comment: Thank you for trying.  Yes and this is why I have used the  <p v-if="lastEvent"> in the p tag so it will only show if it has a value.  Also I have tried initializing lastEvent in various ways as well including const lastEvent = ref([]) and lastEvent = ref() and/or lastEvent = ref(null)

Comment: Watching (more) tutorials.  This seems like there would be an easy solution.  The data is right there visible in the console but completely inaccessible within the document template?

Comment: Not sure, because i cannto try your code without advanced setup.. but could you try replacing `lastEvent.value = docs` with `lastEvent.value.push(...docs)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from getLastEvent being asynchronous (make sure you await your database call before returning lastEvent), what you're returning from the function is an array, while in your Vue file you're using it as if it's an object. Either set lastEvent.value equal to desired element in your array (preferred)

```
const snapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
...
lastEvent.value = docs[0]; // assign value of docs to lastEvent
```

or in your Vue file you can call (though you still need to make your function asynchronous):

```
<p v-if="lastEvent">Last Start Date: {{ lastEvent[0].startDate }}</p>
```

Comment: First, BLESS YOU!  You're first solution worked like a charm - I just needed to reference 
 docs array index of zero - duh seems so simple now!  I would respectfully argue that the await is not needed because snapshot is not taken until getDocs completes via .then. [  getDocs(collectionRef).then(snapshot =>...], etc.  It is working thanks again!!!

Comment: If it works I suppose you don't need it. I'm not familiar with how your backend functions or Firebase in general, I just assumed you needed to wait for a database call somewhere in here.

Comment: If I want to access one of the values in lastEvent from within the setup (not the document template), would that be lastEvent.startDate or lastEvent.value.startDate?

Comment: As it's a ref, you need to use lastEvent.value.startDate. I didn't think of it before, but you probably have to have your return as { lastEvent: lastEvent.value }

Comment: *ignore last part, forgot it was a composable